# Bitmap factory Memory error with smaller images?

Tags: android, memory, bitmapfactory

Hoping someone can help me solve this.

Im making a very simple game on android 4.2.2 using just UI elements, ie no 3D, opengl, Just as a challenge really but I've ran into a little head ache.

I was having O.O.M issues with loading graphics (to be expected with android) so i looked for other routes and found bitmap factory and decided to use a simple implementation. with my images i was hitting up to 40mb allocated memory during game play so I reduced the files from 1080x1920x4bit to 540x960x4bit in a hope to reduce memory load but now it reaches up to 72mb during game play.

Am i missing something or is me thinking, halve the size of images and halve the memory usage? or does upscaling use that much more?

is there any way I can reduce this amount of memory down to a decent 16-20mb range?

Notes on the APP. 
all images are stored in res/no-dp or res/xxdpi. And are all jpegs.

I have six pop up images which are 100x100dp jpegs and 5 x Life segments which are 50x50dp

this is the code im using to load the images from bitmap factory

```
Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dummy1nn);
             button7.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

and im loading the other images as background resources for now via buttons or image views.

I also have soundpool running on elements and a timer.

Any help would be appreciated. I dont want to post all my code as it is a right mess at the minute as im trying many different methods to get this working smoothly. The only issue i have is the memory load.

My current memory after running the game and letting it sit for 5 minutes is:-
Heap size - 73.086mb 
allocated - 70.40mb
free -  2.625mb
used - 96.41%
objects - 47,161

I'm using LG Nexus 5 'hammerhead' as DEV device with unlocked bootloader and stock rom.

Thanks guys. :)

edit:
Answer was to use picasso, although there are a few image libraries out there i liked the simplicity of picasso a lot. and always use MAT when using images to make the relevant changes to quality/size and format to get the lowest memory print (mine dropped to 26mb peak) 
have fun

Comment: Look into using a library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).  You can also read up on loading bitmaps efficiently in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

Comment: First ive heard of picasso, Does it really work or is it just a wrapper/reimplementation of an existing method? have you used it before? any idea on the memory saved? Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: Picasso is great.  With Picasso you can save memory because it will dynamically adjust the bitmap being loaded to only fit inside the View that you're putting it inside of.  So it won't load a 4000x3000 jpeg that might take 20 MB of memory, just to put it into a 200x200 ImageView.  It also takes care of caching and asynchronous loading for you.

Comment: It seems ideal, I am playing with it now, just struggling with the correct useage lol, I'm using this at the moment but it complains of an context must not be null.  "Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.dummy1n).into(button7);" Im sure theres more to it but im struggling to find a decent tut with useage for local files, Was i right to import context? and set as private context?

Comment: `Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.dummy1nn).fit().into(button7);`  Call something like that from your activity.  The Context can just be your Activity, i.e `this` when you call it from your Activity.

Comment: Absolutely flawless. memory is still high but once i apply the rest of the optimizations it should be well below. it fell down to 46mb. but i only used picasso on the 3 background images. i have 13 more to add it to and it should be great after that. Many thanks, if you post as an answer i will gladly accept & thankyou for pointing me to the direction of picasso. do you know of any useful guides at all? be great to get my head round this properly to see if i can add more optimizations :)

Comment: If you wanted to add picasso with a link to the site I will happily accept as answered. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso) is a really good library that will handle memory management, asynchronous loading, and caching for you.

Using your example, it would be used simply like this:

```
Picasso.with(this).load(R.drawable.dummy1nn).fit().into(button7);
```